# Does "An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu" cover differential geometry or should I read about differential geometry before?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, book-recommendation

I want to self-study topology and manifolds to reach knot theory (I've already started with point-set topology) and Im planning on reading "An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu" but I dont know if I will need some differential geometry or if it has differential geometry.

Suggestions of books to read about differential geomtry are appreaciated.
Suggestions on what to read after manifolds are also appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can learn a decent amount of knot theory without knowing any topology or manifold theory. Colin Adams' *The Knot Book* is a fun read: https://www.amazon.com/Knot-Book-Colin-Adams/dp/0821836781

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yeah but I want to know topology too

Comment: Tu's book is pretty much self-contained. You don't need to know any differential geometry before reading it. The exercises in the book are also very doable, and you should try to do them.

Comment: no book can cover differential geometry. Differential geometry its a career in itself. However the book of Tu's is an introduction for some notions on differential geometry

Comment: @Masacroso Yeah, I can imagine that but it isnt the same to read half a chapter of differential geometry than an entire book

Comment: moreover: knot theory is not strongly related to differential geometry, its just a part of algebraic topology